# Cannot override theme's default stylesheet with custom CSS

Tags: wordpress, css

I am trying to override my default CSS in my WordPress theme's settings, but am having a heckuva time doing so.

Here's what my top menu looks like:

[image: menu]

And the same goes for the submenu links when hovering over the top links:

[image: submenu]

I'd like the links to be white ... obviously the blue doesn't show up well at all.

Here's what I get when I Firebug the "About" link:

[image: firebug]

And when I right click the Firebug and copy the HTML, here's what part of it looks like:

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-mega-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-
object-custom level0 has-sub" id="menu-item-3462"><a href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-
up"></i>About<i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
<div class="sub-content" style="display: none;"><ul class="columns">
<li><ul class="list"><li class="header">The Basics</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page level2" id="menu-
item-155"><a href="http://www.occupyhln.org/about-us/">Our Mission</a></li>
```

I've tried using #MashMenu, .menu-mega-menu, .mashmenu, and always do a color:#FFFFFF!important; but nothing ever gets rid of that blue.  I don't know if I provided enough information here, but any help in guiding me in the right direction would be truly appreciated!

My blog is located at http://www.occupyhln.org

Comment: Since they are links, I believe you might need to apply the color DIRECTLY to the `<a>` tag. So `.menu-item a { color: #fff; }`, for example. I dunno, try that.

Comment: Please post a link to your blog. That will make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: http://www.occupyhln.org

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the color is coming from the wordpress theme or from the user agent stylesheets, but the latter do tend to have higher specificity selectors for `a` that will prevent the simple `a` selector from working the way you want.

Inherited values are not related to selectors.  You need to actually select the `a` to override other selectors for its property.  For example:

```
.wordpress-theme a {
    /* Selects <a> and sets the color
    color: blue;
}
#MashMenu {
    /* Selector has higher specificity but does not select <a> */
    color: red;
}
#MashMenu a {
    /* Selects `<a>` with higher specificity */
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Explosion ... I forgot to give the URL, which is http://www.occupyhln.org ... and I'm reading up on specificity right now!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to apply the color override **directly** to the the `<a>` tag your are trying to effect. You probably have something more high-level that is dictating the color.

[Consider this simple example:](http://cdpn.io/chkiw)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='http://google.com'>Here is a link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  color: red;
}

li a {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, Kunalbhat!  I'm still trying to apply this only for the mashmenu, as in my URL, http://www.occupyhln.org ...

Comment: Your problem seems to come from the !important set on the color of .catalyst-widget-area a and .catalyst-widget-area a:visited.

Comment: Hmmm ... I don't know of a way around that.  I do know, however, that at one point I had this working properly.  I'm not sure what I did to screw things up ...

Comment: The easiest way around it is to simply remove that !important. It might have a ripple effect and break something else, but then we can fix that. Adding !important should always be an absolute last resort, because it makes general maintenance so much harder.

Answer (score 1):

The original css is more specific and has the !important value on it. So fight fire with fire and do something like

```
.catalyst-widget-area a, .catalyst-widget-area a:visited, 
.catalyst-widget-area a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

You can narrow the selector even more so you make sure it overrides it.

```
#mashmenu .catalyst-widget-area a, #mashmenu .catalyst-widget-area a:visited, 
#mashmenu .catalyst-widget-area a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

And you can go on and on, making it more specific until it yields.

But here's something I've been wondering, how are you adding all these custom css files to a **Wordpress theme**? I say this, because there's is a right way, and many wrong ways to do it.

The right way is [making a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of your current theme and work it from there. Child themes however, are not for entry-level modifications (though is way easier to override default styles from a child theme), in that case, there are plugins that help you override the css with your own custom css, one of the most popular is [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me).

Comment: Hi, thanks Harrypujols.  The child theme I'm using is Dynamik to go with the Catalyst framework.  I do appreciate your help, but I'm still unable to change the blue.  I did in fact do it once before, but deleted it and forgot how I did so.  Ill keep plugging away!

Comment: Apparently you worked something out with the colors as I see them white now. Now the work is not to display the underline in the hover state of the menu and the bullets in the dropdown list items. Keep narrowing those selectors!

Comment: By the way, if you have access to the file dynamic-min.css, just find the selectors .catalyst-widget-area a, .catalyst-widget-area a:visited, .catalyst-widget-area a:hover, and remove the !important value from the color. It will save you some headaches.

Comment: Thanks Harrypujols -- that's a great idea.  I don't think those !important clauses should be in the main theme stylesheet.  I'll post an answer on how I finally solved the problem in case anybody runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue in case anybody runs into a similar issue, I used the following:

```
.mashmenu .menu>li>a{color:#FFF !important;}
.mashmenu .columns .list a{color:#FFF !important;}
.mashmenu .menu .sub-channel li a{color:#FFF !important;}
.mashmenu .content-item .title a {color:#FFF !important;}
.mashmenu .page-item .title a {color:#FFF !important;}
.mashmenu .page-item a {color:#191970 !important;}
```

But when putting it at the bottom of my custom CSS, it didn't work; when I put it at the beginning of my custom CSS, it worked for some reason.  I have no idea why this is the case, but this is what finally did the trick for me.  Thank you for all who opined and helped me figure this out.